Why is C# DateTime.Now/DateTime.UtcNow ahead of SQL Server's SYSUTCDATETIME()/SYSDATETIME() even though C# code executes before the SQL Query
I want to know the reason why my C# date is larger than the SQL date even though the C# code is running first and after that the SQL query,
Logically the SQL date should be greater than C# date.
For your reference the .NET application and SQL Server are on my local machine.
C# Code:

using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++)
{
    AddRecord();
}
Console.WriteLine("20 records added in database....");

void AddRecord()
{
    try
    {
        string ConnectionString = @"data source=OM5\SQL2019; database=TestDb; integrated security=SSPI";
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand()
            {
                CommandText = "SP_AddRecord",
                Connection = connection,
                CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            };

            SqlParameter param1 = new SqlParameter
            {
                ParameterName = "@CSharp_DateNow",
                SqlDbType = SqlDbType.DateTime2,
                Value = DateTime.Now,
                Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
            };
            cmd.Parameters.Add(param1);

            SqlParameter param2 = new SqlParameter
            {
                ParameterName = "@CSharp_DateUTCNow",
                SqlDbType = SqlDbType.DateTime2,
                Value = DateTime.UtcNow,
                Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
            };
            cmd.Parameters.Add(param2);

            connection.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Exception Occurred: {ex.Message}");
    }
}


SQL:
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Records](
    [Id] [int] PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [SQL_SysDateTime] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [CSharp_DateNow] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [SQL_SysUTCDateTime] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [CSharp_DateUTCNow] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL
)

CREATE OR ALTER   PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_AddRecord]
@CSharp_DateNow datetime2,
@CSharp_DateUTCNow datetime2
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

     insert into Records(SQL_SysDateTime, CSharp_DateNow, SQL_SysUTCDateTime, CSharp_DateUTCNow) values
     (SYSDATETIME(),@CSharp_DateNow,SYSUTCDATETIME(),@CSharp_DateUTCNow)
END

Result in table



SQL_SysDateTime
CSharp_DateNow
Diff. (MS)
SQL_SysUTCDateTime
CSharp_DateUTCNow
Diff. (MS)




2024-07-26 13:26:35.2898391
2024-07-26 13:26:34.9701658
319
2024-07-26 07:56:35.2898391
2024-07-26 07:56:34.9726788
317


2024-07-26 13:26:35.3054610
2024-07-26 13:26:35.3174393
-12
2024-07-26 07:56:35.3054610
2024-07-26 07:56:35.3174492
-12


2024-07-26 13:26:35.3210815
2024-07-26 13:26:35.3217354
0
2024-07-26 07:56:35.3210815
2024-07-26 07:56:35.3217461
0


2024-07-26 13:26:35.3210815
2024-07-26 13:26:35.3261818
-5
2024-07-26 07:56:35.3210815
2024-07-26 07:56:35.3261915
-5


2024-07-26 13:26:35.3367030
2024-07-26 13:26:35.3310309
5
2024-07-26 07:56:35.3367030
2024-07-26 07:56:35.3310384
5


2024-07-26 13:26:35.3367030
2024-07-26 13:26:35.3411312
-5
2024-07-26 07:56:35.3367030
2024-07-26 07:56:35.3411394
-5


2024-07-26 13:26:35.3367030
2024-07-26 13:26:35.3418632
-5
2024-07-26 07:56:35.3367030
2024-07-26 07:56:35.3418676
-5


2024-07-26 13:26:35.3367030
2024-07-26 13:26:35.3430069
-7
2024-07-26 07:56:35.3367030
2024-07-26 07:56:35.3430104
-7


2024-07-26 13:26:35.3367030
2024-07-26 13:26:35.3437519
-7
2024-07-26 07:56:35.3367030
2024-07-26 07:56:35.3437554
-7


2024-07-26 13:26:35.3367030
2024-07-26 13:26:35.3446140
-8
2024-07-26 07:56:35.3367030
2024-07-26 07:56:35.3446172
-8


2024-07-26 13:26:35.3367030
2024-07-26 13:26:35.3452865
-9
2024-07-26 07:56:35.3367030
2024-07-26 07:56:35.3452894
-9


2024-07-26 13:26:35.3367030
2024-07-26 13:26:35.3459309
-9
2024-07-26 07:56:35.3367030
2024-07-26 07:56:35.3459336
-9


2024-07-26 13:26:35.3367030
2024-07-26 13:26:35.3466520
-10
2024-07-26 07:56:35.3367030
2024-07-26 07:56:35.3466552
-10


2024-07-26 13:26:35.3367030
2024-07-26 13:26:35.3475280
-11
2024-07-26 07:56:35.3367030
2024-07-26 07:56:35.3475305
-11


2024-07-26 13:26:35.3367030
2024-07-26 13:26:35.3486445
-12
2024-07-26 07:56:35.3367030
2024-07-26 07:56:35.3486474
-12


2024-07-26 13:26:35.3367030
2024-07-26 13:26:35.3492964
-13
2024-07-26 07:56:35.3367030
2024-07-26 07:56:35.3492991
-13


2024-07-26 13:26:35.3367030
2024-07-26 13:26:35.3501936
-14
2024-07-26 07:56:35.3367030
2024-07-26 07:56:35.3501961
-14


2024-07-26 13:26:35.3367030
2024-07-26 13:26:35.3506370
-14
2024-07-26 07:56:35.3367030
2024-07-26 07:56:35.3506392
-14


2024-07-26 13:26:35.3367030
2024-07-26 13:26:35.3511339
-15
2024-07-26 07:56:35.3367030
2024-07-26 07:56:35.3511362
-15


2024-07-26 13:26:35.3367030
2024-07-26 13:26:35.3517053
-15
2024-07-26 07:56:35.3367030
2024-07-26 07:56:35.3517087
-15



I want an actual reason or an authentic source which can explain this.

Presumably the times on the host you are running the application on and the host hosting SQL Server are different, so you get different values.

@ThomA - The OP said they were the same computer.

I saw that, @Enigmativity, but they also use the connection string OM5\SQL2019, which implies that they are not the same device (as they should be using .\SQL2019 if it's the local device). I've also been "fooled" enough times to always questions when a user says they are using the same device, when they actually aren't.

even if you are calling them at the same time, CPU generally have a scheduler that will create a queue internally. sometimes SQL will get a thread first, sometimes C# will get it first, some times both will get separate threads at the same time.

As an side note as well, the prefix sp_ is reserved, by Microsoft, for Special / System Procedures. It should not be used for User Procedures. Doing so comes with a performance cost and the risk of your Procedure simply not working one day after an update/upgrade. Either use a different prefix or (possibly better) no prefix at all. Is the sp_ prefix still a no-no?

@ShamvilKazmi I have also verified this multiple time and also different machine but the result is same

@ThomA - Fair enough. You make sense.

@ShamvilKazmi the C# code must run before the SQL because it's providing the value to SQL.

Where you noted a difference of -4, the difference is actually -3

@ThomA I want to add one more thing same thing i does with by creating Node Js API and Using same proc but it giving correct time. Their JavaScript time is lesser than Sql time. That is also correct.

i'm guessing some sort of rounding is going on when translating c# datetime to sql datetime which makes it round wrongly. Can you create a table with datetime2 and post the results of that? SYSUTCDATETIME can be used for default

@Shivam you say you used datetime2 but never posted such code. All discrepancies except 3 can be explained by datetime's accuracy and nothing posted in the question shows otherwise. No CREATE TABLE using datetime2(7), no stored procedure with a datetime2(7) parameter and SYSUTCDATETIME default, no C# code using SqlDbType.DateTime2. The 3 remaining cases can be startup, connection or network delays. You've already got an answer to the question.

i was able to replicate this issue in my system.
diff in MICROSECOND
98650
526
-835
-261
-666
-138
-553
-124
-618
-110
-508
-910
-191
-608
-98
-540
-94
-528
-940
-144

@Shivam - It's opened again.

@DaleK Yes me to

These values are precise but not accurate.
If you take the distinct values from SQL_SysDateTime and compare them...
SELECT MS_Diff = DATEDIFF(NANOSECOND, '2024-07-26 13:26:35.2898391', '2024-07-26 13:26:35.3054610')/1E6, 
       MS_Diff = DATEDIFF(NANOSECOND, '2024-07-26 13:26:35.3054610', '2024-07-26 13:26:35.3210815')/1E6, 
       MS_Diff = DATEDIFF(NANOSECOND, '2024-07-26 13:26:35.3210815', '2024-07-26 13:26:35.3367030')/1E6

This returns 15.6219, 15.6205, 15.6215 as differences between them (in ms).
As documented here SQL Server uses GetSystemTimeAsFileTime() for SYSDATETIME()/SYSUTCDATETIME().
Raymond Chen indicates here that by default GetSystemTimeAsFileTime() is not especially accurate though mentions default refresh periods for the value returned by it of 55ms or 10ms rather than 15.62 so presumably this has changed since then.
Various sites indicate that the default timer resolution in Windows 10 is 15.6 ms (or more specifically 15625000ns) so the above gaps are in line with that.
For C# the documentation for DateTime.UtcNow doesn't look any more promising

The resolution of this property depends on the system timer, which
depends on the underlying operating system. It tends to be between 0.5
and 15 milliseconds.

So there is still the question as to how that is achieving the greater accuracy.
You have tagged .NET core. Per this pull request it now calls GetSystemTimePreciseAsFileTime when available (one of the later ones mentioned in the Raymond Chen post above).
On my local machine (Win 11) I do mostly see diffs of around 1ms when running the following test. (But running powercfg -energy does tell me that various processes I have running (including chrome.exe and MongoDB) have requested a low time interval for the Platform Timer Resolution)
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @Times TABLE(insert_time datetime2)

DECLARE @Counter INT = 0

WHILE @Counter < 10000
BEGIN
INSERT @Times VALUES (SYSUTCDATETIME())
SET @Counter+=1;
END


SELECT  [rowcount] = COUNT(*), 
        insert_time, 
        prev_insert_time = LAG(insert_time) OVER (ORDER BY insert_time),
        diff_ms = DATEDIFF(NANOSECOND,LAG(insert_time) OVER (ORDER BY insert_time), insert_time)/1e6
FROM @Times
GROUP BY insert_time

SQL Server doesn't currently have any native way of calling GetSystemTimePreciseAsFileTime and returning datetime2(7) so if this is important to you you will need to do it outside of the database (you could also use CLR integration for this but then the assembly would need to be marked as unsafe to invoke the WinAPI function).
Running the above on Azure SQL database I got the following results so doesn't look like it is refreshed any more frequently there (and you only get ~64 unique values per second).
interestingly replacing SYSUTCDATETIME() with GETUTCDATE() I do get diffs of 3.3333/3.3334 ms so this does appear less precise but more accurate. Presumably this as a result of the "correction" mentioned here.
This situation appears to me to be less than ideal. There is a feedback request Have SYSDATETIME() return value from GetSystemTimePreciseAsFileTime() but it only has 3 votes and is tagged "Archived" so not sure if that means that it will never be considered.



rowcount
insert_time
prev_insert_time
diff_ms




563
2024-07-29 07:21:30.6607494
NULL
NULL


646
2024-07-29 07:21:30.6763740
2024-07-29 07:21:30.6607494
15.6246


659
2024-07-29 07:21:30.6919988
2024-07-29 07:21:30.6763740
15.6248


673
2024-07-29 07:21:30.7076257
2024-07-29 07:21:30.6919988
15.6269


666
2024-07-29 07:21:30.7232517
2024-07-29 07:21:30.7076257
15.626


659
2024-07-29 07:21:30.7390662
2024-07-29 07:21:30.7232517
15.8145


667
2024-07-29 07:21:30.7545026
2024-07-29 07:21:30.7390662
15.4364


660
2024-07-29 07:21:30.7701262
2024-07-29 07:21:30.7545026
15.6236


667
2024-07-29 07:21:30.7857507
2024-07-29 07:21:30.7701262
15.6245


668
2024-07-29 07:21:30.8013755
2024-07-29 07:21:30.7857507
15.6248


664
2024-07-29 07:21:30.8169996
2024-07-29 07:21:30.8013755
15.6241


631
2024-07-29 07:21:30.8326241
2024-07-29 07:21:30.8169996
15.6245


660
2024-07-29 07:21:30.8482510
2024-07-29 07:21:30.8326241
15.6269


662
2024-07-29 07:21:30.8638744
2024-07-29 07:21:30.8482510
15.6234


670
2024-07-29 07:21:30.8795009
2024-07-29 07:21:30.8638744
15.6265


185
2024-07-29 07:21:30.8951255
2024-07-29 07:21:30.8795009
15.6246




But given C# and SQL are reading the same system clock, how can SQL be showing a lower value than C#? I understand the resolution is at 15ms, but surely they should be reading the same value? And how can SQL be showing the same value for multiple calls to the same SP? I guess thats possible if they are all within the same 15ms interval?

Yes it is very expected that SQL will return the same values if called before the time is refreshed. .NET presumably uses some other method behind DateTime.UtcNow than calling GetSystemTimeAsFileTime. Maybe one of the later ones mentioned in Raymond Chen's post

OK that makes sense, do you want to summarise that at the end of your question e.g. "SQL Server appears to be using the default 15ms refresh time as can be seen by the fact that its value doesn't change for multiple calls. Whereas .NET appears to be using one of the more accurate methods and therefore slowly moves ahead of SQL until the end of the refresh period".

though .NET actually isn't documented to be any more accurate The resolution of this property depends on the system timer, which depends on the underlying operating system. It tends to be between 0.5 and 15 milliseconds. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.utcnow?view=net-8.0#remarks

Thats a bit odd thinking about it, 15ms isn't a very high resolution if you're firing lots of updates into SQL.

Weird then that .NET claims to be the same... but the behaviour appears to say otherwise. Its at least a good theory :)

Looks like .NET core made an improvement in this area https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/pull/9736

Good find! Two times slower though... have to call it less :)

You need to use SqlDbType.DateTime2 as it provides higher accuracy.
From the docs
DateTime - Date and time data ranging in value from January 1, 1753 to December 31, 9999 to an accuracy of 3.33 milliseconds. (most of your discrepancy results are in the 3-4 range)
DateTime2 - Date and time data. Date value range is from January 1,1 AD through December 31, 9999 AD. Time value range is 00:00:00 through 23:59:59.9999999 with an accuracy of 100 nanoseconds.

And sysdatetime because getdate returns a datetime. And datetime2 in the proc also.

I have already tried by doing this but the results are same.

@Shivam - please show us a similar table with datetime2
